# How to distinguish two elements with the same class name

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I've tried to target `a.nostyle` in my code, however when I do so, it will sometimes grab the email above as they share the same tags. I can't seem to find any tags unique to the phone number. How would you go about doing so?

SEE IMAGE BELOW. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
a.nostyle:not([itemprop])
```

*UPDATE*

As it seem that BeautifulSoup doesn't support `:not()` syntax, you can try workaround

```
link = [link for link in soup.select('a.nostyle') if 'itemprop' not in link.attrs][0]
```

to select link with required `class` attribute which doesn't contain `itemprop` attribute (as `email` link)

Comment: @Someone... can you elaborate about *"doesn't work"*? Did you get both links or none?

Comment: I got none of the links @Andersson

Comment: @Someone... Can you share code? How you used that selector

Comment: @Andresson target = html.select("a.nostyle:not([itemprop])") --> then looping through all the elements on the site I would assign variable number = target[i].getText() |||||| RESULTING IN INDEX ERROR - INDEX OUT OF RANGE

Comment: And if I try to print the aforementioned target array, it returns an empty array

Comment: @Someone... , why did you use `"a.nostyle:not([html])"` instead of `"a.nostyle:not([itemprop])"`?

Comment: I didn't, mistake in my comment sorry about that @Andersson

Comment: @Someone... , oh, I see. I guess it's a bs4 bug... For some reason bs4 doesn't support `:not` syntax. Try workaround `[link for link in soup.select('a.nostyle') if 'itemprop' not in link.attrs]`

Comment: @Someone... , also it's not the first bug in CSS-selectors handling I faced recently, so I would suggest you to use (IMHO, more convenient and reliable) `lxml.html` instead of BeautifulSoup

Comment: perfect, the workaround works. thanks for the help @Andersson

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list which contains all the "a" tags. Then you can target required tag by using index numbers

Example

```
allATagContainer = soup.findAll("a")
```

then you can use allATagContainer[1] to target second a tag.

Comment: HTML might contain (and probably does) more than two links and this number might be dynamic, so locating link by index is not a good idea

Comment: You are right and I liked your answer more but scraping is a dirty business, I have been in situations when there isn't much I could do except looping through list of tags to get the desirable items.